# How to use Http Client instead of cURL in CakePHP 3

Tags: php, cakephp, curl, httpclient

I want to get data of a URL with sending some POST data. In simple word, as cURL gets data, I want that in cakephp 3. Similar of this code in cakephp 3.

```
$fields = [
    'param1' => 'val1',
    'param2' => 'val2',
];

$fields_string = '';
foreach ($fields as $key => $value)
{
    $fields_string .= $key . '=' . $value . '&';
}
    rtrim($fields_string, '&');

$ch = curl_init();

//set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://www/example.com/api/getcustomerslist');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, count($fields));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);

//execute post
$result = curl_exec($ch);

//close connection
curl_close($ch);
```

I refer this [link](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/httpclient.html) too. But I can not find where to send post method data to get content of the URL. I only found as querystring. i.e, get method as I think. But I want to send request parameters using POST method.

Comment: Post already does this work. post your data on one url then get data and post back to another.

Comment: in cakephp 3 Socket programming here is the link http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/httpclient.html

Comment: You need to read more than just the title of a chapter, you'll usually find what you're looking for in the excellent CakePHP documentation. Honestly, I doubt you read it at all because there are even code examples of what you want right after the listing of the page you linked. http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/httpclient.html#doing-requests Get used to read documentation.